# Error when storing values into mySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to store my data into the database. 
In my script, this worked for me where I have 6 variables including timestamp:

```
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='user', password='pw', database='mydb')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (ts TIMESTAMP, Day0 decimal (5,2), Day1 decimal (5,2), Day2 decimal (5,2), Day3 decimal (5,2), Day4 decimal (5,2), Day5 decimal (5,2))")
sql ="INSERT INTO mytable (ts, Day0, Day1, Day2, Day3, Day4, Day5)" 
sql += "VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql,(day0, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5)) 
print("Storing values into SQL database")
mariadb_connection.commit()
mariadb_connection.close()
```

However, if I wanted to store a single value (float) (value=7.4995244) along with a timestamp, I get a syntax error. Why is this so?

```
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='user', password='pw', database='mydb')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable2 (ts TIMESTAMP, Day0 float(10,8))")
sql ="INSERT INTO mytable2 (ts, Day0)" 
sql += "VALUES (NULL, %s)"  
cursor.execute(sql,(day0)) #the error happens here
print("Storing values into SQL database")
mariadb_connection.commit()
mariadb_connection.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

Comment: In the `cursor.execute` function, try changing syntax to this: `cursor.execute(sql, (Day0, ))`

Comment: Or, you may need to wrap `%s` in speech marks.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I tried the former approach. Why did this problem arise when I have a single value but not when I tried to store more column variables? And what is the significance of adding a ` , ` after my variable, whereas I dont have to do this for the other example?

Comment: *And what is the significance of adding a ` , ` after my variable* --> `x = (4,); x[0]` => 4.  Compare that result to: `x = (4); x[0]` => error.  Another example: `x = (4); x*2` => 8.  Compare that result to: `x = (4,); x*2` => (4, 4).

The function `cursor.execute(sql, values, ...)` has no idea how many values you will need to substitute into your sql statement, so you can imagine that there is source code somewhere that is similar to: `for val in values: #do substitution`.  That means the `values` argument has be a *collection* of values--you can't write `for val in 4:`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is resolved now. As Adam Mitchell advised, I need to do the following:

```
In the cursor.execute function, try changing syntax to this: cursor.execute(sql, (Day0, ))
```